# Как загрузить UserControl в Grid или StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

Создал UserControl и пытаюсь загрузить его на главное окно. В главном окне есть StackPanel и Grid, но куда бы я не пытался добавить UC - одна и та же ошибка -

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Performance.CPUUserControl' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

Вот код -

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CPUUserControl cPUUser = new CPUUserControl();

        UserControlGrid.Children.Add(cPUUser);
        StackPanelUserControl.Children.Add(cPUUser);
        //MainFrame.Navigate(cPUUser);
    }
```

Как добавить UC в окно?

Comment: WPF - это MVVM с привязками, xaml разметкой и др. То есть другими словами `.Children.Add` в WPF не уместен, это нужно забыть и оставить в WinForms!

Comment: Что у вас за UserControl такой, что он не наследует UIElement? Покажите заголовок объявления класса

Comment: @АндрейNOP просто правой добавил UC. Правой кнопкой нажала по проекту -> add -> User Contro. Кстати в нем нет xaml designer. 
[Залил на Git проект](https://github.com/xomem/Perfomance), может так будет понятнее.

Comment: Вы добавили не тот UserControl, вместо WPF добавлен UserControl из WinForms. Необходимо при добавлении в окне Add New Item в левом дереве выбирать ветку WPF.

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо. Жаль... В этом UC нет элемента Chart, который мне очень нужен. Получается в WPF нет Charts? Вы, случайно, не знаете как в wpf графики рисовать?

Comment: С помощью [OxyPlot](http://www.oxyplot.org), например.

Comment: @АндрейNOP так это очень старая библиотека

Comment: Полтора года назад был выпущен последний стабильный релиз, не такая уж и старая, вы думаете Майкрософт вам стандартные контролы каждый месяц обновляет? :) Ну и вроде как следующая версия на подходе. В любом случае вы вправе выбрать любую другую платную или бесплатную альтернативу.

Comment: если действительно очень нужен, в WPF можно размещать контроллы WinForms, [пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf)